# Stuck in regex/markdown replacement issue (double matches and replace using data from the matches)

Tags: regex, awk

So here is my problem

Sample input (file.txt)

```
all chars possible

[[example.org]][1500]

all chars possible

[[example.org]][1318]

all chars possible

[1318]: https://web.example.org/web/https://example.com
[1500]: https://web.example.org/web/https://example.net

all chars possible
```

Sample desired output (file.txt)

```
all chars possible

[[example.org]](https://web.example.org/web/https://example.net)

all chars possible

[[example.org]](https://web.example.org/web/https://example.com)

all chars possible

(basically again every special char)
```

For the first match, brackets are constant, number is variable and can be 1-4 numbers in length. `[[example.org]][variable number]`

For the second match brackets are constant, semi colon as well, number is variable 1-4 in length and matching the previous variable number (reference in markdown),followed by a space and then any URL possible, http with any URL char possible BUT always starts with https://web.example.org/web/)

So I want to replace things as follows

```
[[example.org]][1500]

By (for every matching number without being hampered by the ton of special chars in the file)

[[example.org]](URL)

In this case

[[example.org]](https://web.exampe.org/web/https://example.net)
```

And then remove the `[1500]: https://web.example.org/web/https://example.net` after modification

Ending with:

```
(tons of special chars/text/url)

[[example.org]](https://web.example.org/web/https://example.net)

(tons of special chars/text/url)
```

The first regex I made is:

```
\[\[example.org\]\]\[([0-9]{1,4})\]
```

Capture group 1 getting [1500]

The second regex I made is:

```
[1500\]: (.*)
```

Capture group getting the URL in a dirty way

Yet it should be using the capture group 1 from above so ended with this

```
\1: (.*)
```

And I want to end up with only the first matched regex as follows instead of a numbered reference. I'm stuck here.

```
[[example.org]](captured URL)
```

Followed by removal of the entire line (no space left)

```
[1500]: URL
```

I tried some JS but got stuck by all the special chars in the document breaking things. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I don't know if/how this is possible with a simple search/replace using regexes. And I'm sure there must be an easy way to do this maybe using sed. This is for help for our open-source project and I admit I'm not the best at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `gnu-awk` solution will be a better fit here:

```bash
awk -F ': ' '{
   gsub(/^[[:blank:]]+/, "")
}
FNR == NR {
   if (NF==2)
      map[$1] = $2
   next
}
match($0, /\[\[Archive\.org]](\[[0-9]+])/, a) && a[1] in map {
   $0 = substr($0, 1, RSTART+RLENGTH-length(a[1])-1) "(" map[a[1]] ")" substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH)
}
$1 !~ /^\[[0-9]+]$/ || !($1 in map)' file file

all chars possible

[[example.org ]](https://web.example.org/web/https://example.net)

all chars possible

[[example.org ]](https://web.example.org/web/https://example.com)

all chars possible
```